# How to update QML property from within fuction

Tags: python, pyqt, qml, pyside, qtquick2

I'm trying to display text message on screen, when barcode is detected via OpenCV, from within long running background thread, but nothing that I've tried worked so far.
I'm confused by slight differences between PySide and PyQt and most examples deal with user interactions.
Could someone give me a simple example if possible of how to achieve that?
Much appreciated.

```py
import os, sys, cv2, threading, time
from multiprocessing import Process
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, Signal, Property, QUrl, QTimer, QDateTime
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


class TextManager(QObject):

    textChanged = Signal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QObject.__init__(self, parent)
        self._text = ""

    def get_text(self):
        return self._text

    def set_text(self, value):
        if self._text == value:
            return
        self._text = value
        self.textChanged.emit()


class CamWorker(QObject):
    def scanner(self):
        camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        def decodeCam(image):
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            barcodes = pyzbar.decode(gray)
            if detected:
                changeQMLProperty
            return image
            
        while True:
                    # Read current frame
            try:
                ret, frame = camera.read()
                im=decodeCam(frame)
            except ValueError:
                print("error")
    

def run():
    app = QtGui.QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    manager = TextManager()
    directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
    engine.load('qml/main.qml')
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    engine.rootObjects()[0].setProperty('manager', manager)
    worker = CamWorker()
    threading.Thread(target=worker.scanner, daemon=True).start()

    return app.exec_()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(run())
```

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
  id: testing
  visible: true
  width: 640
  height: 480
  Text{
    anchors.fill: parent
    text: manager.text
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a call to `set_text`, can you explain how you intended that to happen? I think you probably want to give the `manager` to the `CamWorker` to be able to call `set_text`?

Comment: I don't know python so I advice you as general. You should declaring a QObject based class and register it to make it usable in qml. Declare a Qt/QML property in that class ([doc](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/overviews/properties.html#a-simple-example)). Use it in qml by binding it to the Text element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use QML types for getting video from camera here is a simple example:
File *main.py*

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from PySide6.QtCore import QObject, Slot, Signal, QRunnable, QThreadPool
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication, QImage
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine, QmlElement
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pyzbar import pyzbar
import random 

QML_IMPORT_NAME = "com.myapp.components"
QML_IMPORT_MAJOR_VERSION = 1


class Worker(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, emiter: Signal, image: QImage):
        super().__init__(None)
        self.image = image
        self.emiter = emiter

    def qimage_to_array(self, image: QImage) -> np.ndarray:
        """Converts a QImage into an opencv MAT format"""
        image = image.convertToFormat(QImage.Format.Format_RGBA8888)
        width = image.width()
        height = image.height()

        ptr = image.constBits()
        return np.array(ptr).reshape(height, width, 4)

    def run(self):
        arr = self.qimage_to_array(self.image)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(arr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        barcodes = pyzbar.decode(gray)
        # logic here.
        # returning now random boolean
        self.emiter.emit(random.choice([True, False]))


@QmlElement
class Cv2Capture(QObject):
    imageAnalayized = Signal(bool)

    @Slot(int, QImage)
    def receive(self,req_id, image: QImage):
        worker = Worker(self.imageAnalayized, image)
        QThreadPool.globalInstance().start(worker)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    qml_file = Path(__file__).parent / "main.qml"
    engine.load(qml_file)
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

File *main.qml*

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtMultimedia
import com.myapp.components
import QtQuick.Controls.Material


ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainFrame
    Material.theme: Material.Dark
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Cam Test")

    Cv2Capture {
        id: bridge
        onImageAnalayized: function(res){console.log(res)}
    }

    Rectangle {id: rect
        width: 640
        height: 400

        MediaDevices {
            id: mediaDevices
        }

        CaptureSession {
            imageCapture: ImageCapture {
                id: capture
                onImageCaptured: function(req_id, preview){bridge.receive(req_id, preview)}
            }
            camera: Camera {
                id: camera
            }
            videoOutput: output
        }

        VideoOutput {
            id: output
            anchors.fill: parent
        }

        Button {
            id: startCamButton
            text: "Start Cam"
            anchors.top: output.bottom
            anchors.left: output.left
            onClicked: {
                camera.start()
                camImage.opacity = 0
            }
        }

        Button {
            id: takePicButton
            text: "take pic"
            anchors.top: output.bottom
            anchors.left: startCamButton.right
            onClicked: {
                capture.capture()
                camImage.opacity = 1
            }
        }

        Image {
            id: camImage
            anchors.fill: parent
            source: capture.preview
        }
    }
}
```

This example uses PySide6 which has better support for QML than PySide2.

> I'm confused by slight differences between PySide and PyQt

PyQt and PySide are both Python bindings of the C++ library called Qt.
PyQt - made by riverbanks.
PySide - by Qt company.

##### Explanation:

The `QmlElement`, [as described here](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/tutorials/qmlintegration/qmlintegration.html), decorator will register the class to be used in QML.
every `Signal` you create in that class would be available in QML
in the type instantiation e.g:

```
Cv2Capture {
    id: bridge
    onImageAnalayized: function(res){console.log(res)}
}
```

Where `onImageAnalayized` was `imageAnalayized = Signal(bool)` in Python.
slots are also available via calling them with the component `id`.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use Pyside6 and thus QmlElement.

Comment: With PySide2 you can use `qmlRegisterType` and drop the import statement. BTW why you can't?

Comment: All distros that I'm using it on aren't supporting/providing Pyside6. Raspberry Pi OS being one of them.